# Understanding and implementing routes and db access in Pyramid

Tags: python, view, sqlalchemy, frontend, pyramid

I am trying to figure out the best method of accessing all the matching `microseries` found in the `Assessment` class (table) in my database. I am trying to create a link that will send a user to those matching `microseries`. I am new and want to better understand the nuts and bolts of front-end engineering. I also have not seen a similar question asked here on Stacks.

I am not using JSON or XML yet, so this is a static HTML process. I have a few routes that access assessments at the moment, e.g.:

```
config.add_route('assessments', '/assessments')
config.add_route('assessment', '/assessments/{id:\d+}')
```

What I would like to better understand while implementing a method of finding matching `microseries` in the `Assessment` table and sending the user to a new page with those matching series: 
How `routes` work, especially when accessing an attribute of a class, e.g. `Assessment.microseries`.

The goal of `View` code to convey the method mentioned above. 
[Pyramid links](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/config.html#pyramid.config.Configurator.add_route) and [Pyramid on Routes](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/urldispatch.html#route-pattern-syntax) and [URL Dispatch](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/urldispatch.html#url-dispatch)

*Using: Python 2.7, SQLAlchemy, Pyramid*

---

Assessment table:

```
class Assessment(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'assessments'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50), unique=True)
    text = Column(String(2000))
    microseries = Column(Integer)
    # more code

    def __init__(self, name, text, user, video, categories, microseries):
            # more code
```

*API for interacting with an assessment is based on CRUD- create, retrieve, update and delete.*

View Code: 
**this is not doing what I need it to do as I don't have a form of link to send the user to the matching series, e.g. Link1 would send a user to a new view with  `GET` for all subseries of Link1: 1a, 1b, 1c....**

```
@view_config(route_name='assessments', request_method='GET', renderer='templates/unique_assessments.jinja2', permission='create')
def view_unique_microseries_group(request):
    logged_in_userid  = authenticated_userid(request)
    if logged_in_userid is None:
        raise HTTPForbidden()
    all_assessments = api.retrieve_assessments() #all assessments in a list
    assessments_by_microseries = {} #dictonary
    for x in all_assessments:
        if x.microseries in assessments_by_microseries:
            print("Already seen this microseries: %s" % x.microseries)
        else:
            assessments_by_microseries[x.microseries] = x
    unique_assessments = sorted(assessments_by_microseries.values()) #.values() method to get the, err, values of the dict.
    print 'unique_assessments:', unique_assessments
    #a = HTTPSeeOther(location=request.route_url('view_microseries'))
    return {'logged_in': logged_in_userid, 'unique_assessments': unique_assessments} #need to send some kind of list that can be shown on the template to send a user to the appropriately matching set of microseries
```

Comment: Is URL dispatch a hard requirement (note: it should not)? CRUD like controllers have more elegant solutions using traverse pattern instead of URL dispatch pattern. Would you like to see a traverse solution?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa yes please!

Comment: ok let me return to this later this week - I am little bit overloaded at the moment, but no Pyramid question shall go unanswered.

Comment: You are awesome Mikko. I appreciate the (future) explanation to further Pyramid/Python knowledge.